# PyCharm mark directory as excluded via flag in the filesystem?

Tags: pycharm

I would like to exclude some directories as excluded in PyCharm via a flag in the matching directory.

Example: Our tests create a directory called `.reports`.

I know how to exclude this directory in my PyCharm instance.

But we have many developers and many projects. I really would like to avoid every developer needing to mark this directory as excluded.

Is there a way to tell PyCharm to skip this file?

For example by creating an empty file called ".pycharm-exclude"?

I am looking for an automated way to exclude the directory, since we have several developers and each developer has several projects.

I created a feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-51093

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any way similar to an ignore file since it seems PyCharm wants you to use it's GUI for configuration. However, if you're flexible to a different approach...

Take a look at the default file/directory ignore list at `Settings | Editor | File Types | Ignore files and subfolders`

You can rename `.reports` -> `.reports~`, `.reports.pyc`, `.reports.rbc`, `.svn`, etc. and PyCharm will ignore it.

By default PyCharm ignores a number of patterns/names because they are common non project names. If you name a directory something which matches one of those patterns/names then you can trick PyCharm into ignoring that directory. There are ~20 patterns/names which are ignored by default (found at the path above) so I'd choose whatever creates the least confusion in the team / prevent some problem I'm unaware of.

If you wanted a more sensible name you could add `.report;` to this list as **this list persists across all projects**, but every developer would need to update it once.

For the sake of others who see this, there is also the more common exclude list at `Settings | Project: ... | Project Structure | Exclude files`, which defaults to empty and does NOT persist across projects

Comment: thank you. Nevertheless I would like to avoid that every developer needs to do this. It would be great if a special file in the directory would tell the IDE to stop looking into this directory.

Comment: @guettli I've updated my answer to provide a solution which I think should do what you're asking for (Not the cleanest IMO, but... I think it should work)

Comment: that's cool. So `.reports~` should work. Thank you.

Comment: I missed that one. I like that a-lot more than the ones I had. Updated list to include it

Comment: Nice solution. Perhaps you could rephrase the question a bit so that it's more obvious that renaming the directory is an option and then accept @nanotek's answer. :-)

Comment: @jboot, Ya, I was thinking about it and I feel like your answer actually tries to address the question as it's asked (although I'd have some concerns about doing that, but I thought it was interesting), and I did the classic ignore OP's question and answer a completely different question. If he couldn't rename the dir, my answer would be mostly pointless. I've gotten in trouble on SO for editing a question in a way that would change the answers given, so I'm not sure what would be 'right'. OP has far more rep than me though, so I trust he knows what's best.Maybe someone else knows a way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a file that works the way that you describe. However, you *can* take a look at your idea's project file `.idea/<project>.iml` (where `<project>` is your project's name). So let's say your project is called `your-app`, then it can be found under `.idea/your-app.iml`. It should describe the excluded folder somewhere like this:

```xml
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.reports" />
    </content>
  </component>
```

You could create a fresh clone of the repository, open it in PyCharm, exclude the folder and commit the `your-app.iml` file.

It's not perfect as it might override your colleagues' settings when they check it out, but it basically gives them a template file that excludes that folder. You should probably then add the file to the `.gitignore` file so that no one overwrites the shared file afterwards:

```
# .gitignore
# exclude .idea folder
.idea/

# or just the file
.idea/your-app.iml
```

If the file is already ignored by git, you might have to add it with the force flag:

```sh
git add -f .idea/your-app.iml
```

In that case you probably won't have to add it to any `.gitignore` file afterwards.

**Note:** I have not tested this. I expect it might introduce conflicts or overwrite the `your-app.iml` file for developers that already have it in their local repository. It probably works best for *new* projects.

Comment: I am looking for an automated way to exclude the directory, since we have several developers and each developer has several projects. Can you solution be automated?

Comment: It can, but it won't be straightforward as the name changes per project and I'm not sure the file's _entire_ content can easily be generated. I expect that it will require a complex script, or some one-time only user interaction per repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the project `.idea/<project-name>.iml` using code like this:

#### Code to edit IML file

```py
from pathlib import Path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

EXCLUDE_PREFIX = 'file://$MODULE_DIR$'
idea_dir = Path('.idea')  # pycharm stores the project files in .idea
project_file = next(idea_dir.glob('*.iml'), None) if idea_dir.exists() else None

if project_file is None:
    # we expect to be in the project root directory
    exit(1)

project_file = project_file.resolve()
tree = et.parse(project_file)
module_dir = tree.find(".//content[@url='file://$MODULE_DIR$']")

if module_dir is None:
    # add a node for the NewModuleRootManager
    root_manager = tree.find(".//component[@name='NewModuleRootManager']")
    module_dir = et.SubElement(root_manager, 'content', url='file://$MODULE_DIR$')

# find which exclude directories we need to add
existing_excludes = {Path(f.attrib['url'].replace(EXCLUDE_PREFIX, '.'))
                     for f in module_dir.findall("excludeFolder")}
desired_excludes = {f.parent for f in idea_dir.parent.rglob('.pycharm-exclude')}
new_excludes = sorted(f'{EXCLUDE_PREFIX}/{f}' for f in desired_excludes - existing_excludes)

# add the needed exclude directories and save the file
if new_excludes:
    for exclude in new_excludes:
        et.SubElement(module_dir, 'excludeFolder', url=exclude)
    et.indent(tree)  # this expects python 3.9
    tree.write(str(project_file), xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

#### How does this work?

The project `.iml` file is xml.  We can read in the XML using [`etree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and then edit it accordingly.  It is straight forward to look for our marker file, and then add the `excludeFolder` nodes to the xml as needed.  The relevant portion of the `.iml` file xml looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/exclued_dir" />
    </content>
  </component>
</module>
```